# C# - Фильтр в эксель с использованием цикла

Tags: c#, excel, com

Подскажите как можно сделать следующие:

В C# открываю документ эксель(это есть). В котором нужно вставить фильтр по колонке С, затем из ранее сформированого List(это есть) взять значение ID, применить его в фильтре, найти строку в которой это значение, и затем изменить  значение ячейки G, ,берем следующее значение из List...и т.д.

Comment: ID - это число у вас? `найти строку в которой это значение` - строку с номером ID? Какой библиотекой пользуетесь?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, ID - содержит и буквы и цифры. Да строку (как это обычно в экселе происходит когда используешь фильтр.) Основная библиотека Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Comment: Ну или как вариант.Сделать тоже самое но без фильтра. Поиск значения из Листа в колонке С, и затем изменение значения в колонке G в строке которая соответствует найденному значению., ищем вторую записть в листе и т.д.

Comment: Сейчас попробую одну вещь и, возможно, помогу вам

Comment: Вообще рекомендую в дальнейшем пользоваться библиотекой `ClosedXML` или `EPPlus`. Могу показать сейчас, как писать фильтры на ClosedXML.

Comment: А с помощью стандартной майкрософтовской - есть функция у класса `Excel.Range` - AutoFilter(). Туда кидаете нужные параметры - и ваш фильтр готов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось проще чем я думал. Через функцию Find вместо фильтра.

```
foreach(string ID in List_ID)
{
  Excel.Range range_find=wrkSheet.get_Range(C:C).Find(ID);
  int num_row=Convert.ToInt16(range_find.Rows.Row);
  wrkSheet.Cells[num_row, 7] = "1";
  wrkSheet.Cells[num_row, 7].Interior.ColorIndex = 3; //Закрасить измененную ячейку в красный
}
```